# Spider/Crawler for testing an AJAX web app that requires a session cookie?

Tags: ajax, session, cookies, web-crawler

We have a web app that is heavy on AJAX and it is very customizable so we need something that will click on every link in it to make sure that none of the forms/pages break. I know that there are lots of spiders/crawlers out there but we haven't been able to find one that's easy to implement and works with AJAX and allows you to have a session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering you asked this question over two years ago I doubt you'll have much need for the answer.  But in case someone else comes across this question from a search engine, here's my suggestion:

Use Selenium http://seleniumhq.org/ or IEUnit https://code.google.com/p/ieunit/ to automate a browser itself.  They both operate on top of a JavaScript engine so you can write a few lines of code to click on every anchor tag in your site.